# connecting to SQLSERVER database without remote connection

Tags: .net, sql-server, ftp

We are making a mobile application for a company. They want us to show some data on mobile application, from their database. They use SQL Server 2008 R2 as they say. Problem is they have given an ftp address username and password, and user information of database (server address, username, password, database name). But the funny thing is they dont open their database to remote connection. I guess they expect me to write some code send it with ftp to the server and make http requests to that file. but since i dont know any of the table names this is nonsense, furthermore even if I write a .net web service or web application is it possible to publish it over an ftp? I am really confused here, wondering what should I do? I guess I somehow need to force the other company to allow remote connection with us. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess I somehow need to force the other company to allow remote connection with us. Am I wrong?

Very wrong, you hardly ever need remote connections to a database. An HTTP service in front of the database is the way to go. Would you otherwise hardcode the database credentials in the application you distribute and hope the T-SQL TCP port is opened for outgoing traffic in the user's firewall?

> since i dont know any of the table names this is nonsense

Then ask them for a diagram.

> even if I write a .net web service or web application is it possible to publish it over an ftp?

Of course, why not?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen each of your questions is worth an own question, and I'm sure that on each subject there's enough to find on this site and the web in general. If you're having trouble implementing something specific, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: No I actually - thanks to your straight answers - was able to implement the things I needed. I really needed to find out that I was thinking wrong, you made it clear. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would clarify with them what they want you to do.  Secondly I would ask for a table schema.  If not, there are a number of commands you can use within SQL to show database information (sys.tables...etc).

Expanding upon the other answer, you could use Web Services of some kind, whether it be classic SOAP, WCF, Web.Api.

If they were to open up the port to allow remote connections, then ensure its only open to the specific IP address of your site/application.